# Apache2 / phpmyadmin - PHP isn't working

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I was working on a project of mine . then i had to restart the computer.
Once I did suddenly **PHP** stopped working on **Apache**. then i starting looking into the configuration files and error logs and fixed a spelling error in the config file, but **STILL** the problem persisted, then i decided to re-install **phpmyadmin** and **Apache2** and ran:

```
apt-get --purge remove apache2 apache2-utils && apt-get --purge remove phpmyadmin
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2 phpmyadmin
```

then I set **phpmyadmin** to configure everything automatically but the very same problem persisted O-O , so i do NOT understand what am i doing wrong or how to fix it so your assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you are trying to do and as a result what error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already Fixed IT! ( kinda )

- I backed up my `/var/www/` folder just in case
- I purged apache2 php7 and mysql with : `apt-get --purge remove PackageName`
- I installed apache2 and php5 and mysql
- then I installed "libapache2-mod-php5"

  ---

and then i just added the line `"Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf"` and 
`"ServerName localhost"` to the apache2 config located in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Comment: Check out the /wamp/alias directory, this is where you would store your custom configurations.